# Angular HttpClient Typechecking Post Request's Repsonse

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Is it possible to use type checking for POST (and type of other requests) with the new HttpClient in Angular (4.3+) as well? The official documentation  (https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response) only mentions GET requests:

```
interface ItemsResponse {
  results: string[];
}

...

http.get<ItemsResponse>('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
   // data is now an instance of type ItemsResponse, so you can do this:
   this.results = data.results;
});
```

Does it work for other kind of requests the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, it does. For example

```
interface LoginResponse {
    token: string;
}

...
this.http.post<LoginResponse>(url, body, options).subscribe(
    data => {
        this.jwtoken = data.token;
        return 'Login successful';
    },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```